# Showing that a matrix cannot be obtained as an element of a one parameter subgroup of $SL(2; R)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have to show that the matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda & 0 \\
0 & -\frac{1}{\lambda}
\end{bmatrix}

cannot be obtained as an element of a one parameter subgroup of $SL(2; R)$ except when $\lambda = 1$. Additionally, show that it can be obtained as a combination of paths $e^Ae^B$ and find $A$ and $B$.

I don't even know how do I start proving this result. Given a one parameter subgroup, I can verify versus some element or list all the elements but I need help with this.

Comment: It isn't even in $SL(2;R)$: the determinant is $-1$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Sorry, typo! The first element is $-\lambda$

Comment: One parameter subgroups arise from taking the matrix exponential of some element in your lie algebra, right? Then if you had some two by two matrix that mapped to your given matrix you could compute the coefficients. Maybe those coefficients lead to a contradiction?

Comment: @NikolasWojtalewicz Right! I see that. So, the parameter won't satisfy $A(s+t) = A(s) A(t)$,

Answer (score 1):

Hint: eigenvalues.  What are the eigenvalues of $\exp(tA)$ in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: So, $e^{t a_1} = -\lambda$ and $e^{t a_2} = -\frac{1}{\lambda}$, and $a_1$, $a_2$ are complex eigenvalues of $A$. I really don't see how this is a contradiction

Comment: BTW, nobody said $\lambda > 0$.  If $\lambda$ is allowed to be negative, you can indeed have your matrix in a one-parameter subgroup.

Comment: If $\lambda > 0$ and $\lambda \ne 1$, $a_1$ and $a_2$ are non-real, but are not complex conjugates.